# How do I render a pandas dataframe and a matplotlib chart side-by-side in Quarto using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, latex, quarto

I'm trying to make a dashboard of plots and tables in Quarto using Python. As a test, I'm trying to get a pandas dataframe to render side-by-side with a matplotlib chart. The alignment is off, `layout` seems to work fine but `layout-ncol` doesn't seem to work with Python. And `layout-valign` doesn't seem to work either.

Example code below

````
---
title: "Column Test"
format: pdf
---

::: {layout="[1,1]" layout-valign="top"}
:::: {#first-column}
```{python}
#| echo: false
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
dates = [dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=n) for n in range(100)]
values = range(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'values':values})
ax = df.set_index('date').plot()
```
::::
:::: {#second-column}
```{python}
#| echo: false
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],
                [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df
```
::::
:::
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `layout` or `layout-ncol`, we may follow the tricks [described in the R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html) which works fine in case of Quarto too.

Define two new environment `columns` and `column` and use them in the pandoc divs (`:::`).

**columns.tex**

```
\newenvironment{columns}[1][]{}{}

\newenvironment{column}[1]{\begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}{%
\end{minipage}
\ifhmode\unskip\fi
\aftergroup\useignorespacesandallpars}

\def\useignorespacesandallpars#1\ignorespaces\fi{%
#1\fi\ignorespacesandallpars}

\makeatletter
\def\ignorespacesandallpars{%
  \@ifnextchar\par
    {\expandafter\ignorespacesandallpars\@gobble}%
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
```

In the Quarto document, include the above tex file using `include-in-header` and then Wrap the contents you want to put side by side inside the `columns` div and then wrap each component within the `column` div. Note that, `column` divs needs to nested within the `columns` div, so use one extra `:` for `columns` div.
Use `data-latex` to specify the content width and note that I have used a blank `column` div to create some space between the content. Also note that, all of the `column` div width should be summed to 1.

````
---
title: "Column Test"
format: pdf
include-in-header: column.tex
---

:::: {.columns data-latex=""}

::: {.column data-latex="{0.60\textwidth}"}

```{python}
#| echo: false

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
dates = [dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=n) for n in range(100)]
values = range(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'values':values})
ax = df.set_index('date').plot()
```

\captionof{figure}{A meaningless figure}
\label{fig:myfigure}

:::

::: {.column data-latex="{0.03\textwidth}"}
\ 
<!-- an empty Div (with a white space), serving as
a column separator -->
:::

::: {.column data-latex="{0.37\textwidth}"}
```{python}
#| echo: false
#| label: tbl-mytable
#| tbl-cap: A meaningless Table
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],
                [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df
```

:::

::::

See \autoref{fig:myfigure} and @tbl-mytable
````

#### Caveats

Now there is a problem with this approach that we need to be aware of. If want to use a caption and want to refer to the figure later, we may be tempted to use `fig-cap` along `label` chunk option. But using these will break this solution. Because the `column` is environment is created based on `minipage` environment and using the aforementioned chunk options will create a `figure` environment. And `figure` environment must not be used inside a `minipage`.

So if we want to use figure caption and cross-referencing, we need to use raw latex commands `captionof` (from the `caption` latex package) and `label`, just after the figure code chunk.

**rendered-output**

---

[image: chart and table side by side]